# Desmembrar data para carregar no javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Tenho no BD um campo DataNascimento, onde é gurdada no formato YYYY-mm-dd. Tenho uma função javascript que varre a tabela pelo CPF passado. Caso haja registro para o CPF, então ele monta os campos no formulário. Acontece, que a Data de Nascimento, no formulário, é montada com três objetos option(Combobox), assim:
Dia Mes Ano.

Como eu faço na minha controller um método que me retorne a Data do BD desmembrada, para eu carregar no meu formulário?

Uso LINQ assim:

```
var Result = (from a in db.TB_CLIENTES
                              where a.CdCliente == "1" && a.CPF == _cpf
                              select new
                              {
                                  a.Nome,
                                  a.Endereco,
                                  a.Numero,
                                  a.CEP,
                                  a.Complmento,
                                  a.Telefone,
                                  a.Celular

                              }).ToList();
```

Comment: Qual é o tipo da propriedade `DataNascimento` em seu modelo de domínio? É `string`, ou é `DateTime`?

Comment: Resolvi assim: Dia = a.DataNascimento.Value.Day,
                                  Mes = a.DataNascimento.Value.Month,
                                  Ano = a.DataNascimento.Value.Year, completando o meu LINQ

Answer (score 1):

```cs
var Result = (from a in db.TB_CLIENTES
    where a.CdCliente == "1" && a.CPF == _cpf
    select new
    {
        Nome = a.Nome,
        Endereco = a.Endereco,
        Numero = a.Numero,
        CEP = a.CEP,
        Complemento = a.Complemento,
        Telefone = a.Telefone,
        Celular = a.Celular,
        DiaNascimento = a.DataNascimento.Value.Day,
        MesNascimento = Ano = a.DataNascimento.Value.Month,
        AnoNascimento = a.DataNascimento.Value.Year
    }).ToList();
```